# Why is google not using a headless browser to crawl clientside content?

Tags: ajax, seo, client-side, web-crawler

I'm aware of the steps it takes to make a client side website crawlable:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=nl

I just wonder, why isn't Google just integrating a headless browser *in* their crawlers to save us the pain of providing html snapshots via e.g. NodeJS and a server side DOM implementation?

I guess their might be a technical reason that I'm missing. I just don't see it.

Comment: Why the close vote? How can that be off topic?

Comment: This is a good question. Don't know whether anyone on stackoverflow can answer it though :) We should ask google. Especially since they are supporting angularjs..

Comment: Recently some Googlers said, they were working on that :)

Comment: Another interesting question shut down.

Comment: My best questions usually are closed for no obvious reason. :)