# benefit of using angular js on top of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Is there much point to using angular js on top of asp.net mvc since they're kind of both doing the same thing?  What are the advantages to using angular over asp.net mvc + jquery?  What kind of scenario would you pick angular in?  If you do pick angular in a microsoft environment, what would you run on the server side?  Would it be something like Web API?  Or is there still benefit of using traditional asp.net mvc?

Comment: client side could care less what framework or language you run on server

Comment: i noticed the negative votes. should this be asked elsewhere or worded differently?

Comment: I dont think the -ve votes are fair. I had to ask the same question myself few months ago. I think I made the right choice (for now) by using both as needed. Please see my answer below

Comment: I had a similar doubt but didn't see your question, so I asked the same question and guess what...I too received negative votes. I would have understood if my question was marked as duplicate but still couldn't understand why it was down-voted.

Comment: @Riz I am glad, that I found your link and found answers to my question. Thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On my site http://www.reviewstoshare.com, I am using AngularJS along with ASP.NET MVC. **The main reason I did not go all the way with AngularJS was that SEO is not easily achieved with AngularJS.** 
Keep in mind that my site was already built using ASP.MVC + Jquery for in page interaction as needed.

On the other hand there is still some "Ajaxy" nature to the site like comments, voting, flagging etc. Not too different than Stackoverflow itself. Before AngularJS it was a mess of Jquery plugins and functions within `$(document).ready()` callback, not to mention the JS code was not testable much.

In the end, I went with both.

Comment: @Ketan The mentioned site  http://www.reviewstoshare.com is not accessible/ reachable or down.

Answer (score 25):

This question is a bit subjective, however here was our reasoning.

1. *Let the client handle rendering of pages*, free up resources on the server.
2. *Leverage built in caching of cache servers* since we are just dealing with `<html/>` content.
3. Since the pages are cached the *only traffic back and forth is json payloads*.
4. We have been using *[NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org)*, but WebAPI or Service Stack would work just fine.
5. *We wanted to build a responsive single page application* and AngularJs fit the bill for testability as full feature rich framework.
6. *AngularJs forces you into a pattern* that we needed for JavaScript, in the past our jQuery heavy applications turned into functional spaghetti (That was our fault but being guided by Angular helped out a lot).

**As with all frameworks pick the one that suites your needs**

Comment: There are SEO implications with client side js frameworks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy using Java Script framework then Angular JS rocks.
SEO could be the issue. You need to have deeper understanding of DOM and Java Script as compared to other famous JS Frameworks.
I ve developed a Proof of Concept - using Angular JS with Require JS using ASP.net MVC
You can have a look at it at the below given link
http://angualrjsrequirejsaspmvc.blogspot.com/2013/08/angular-js-with-require-js-front-end.html

Comment: I just went through your project but there's nothing helpful in there. No angular js, nothing much in the views except for some boilerplate code.