# Can ngView and SEO go together?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

For obvious SEO reasons, I'm filling up the initial landing page contents inside the ngView on server side.

Is there a way to tell angular to not touch the ngView for the initial page load && for the specific landing route?

Comment: obvious reasons?...or myths? perhaps explaing these obvious reasons would be good idea

Comment: r u cereal? in what other way would i get engines to index the content other than rendering the stuff server-side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)