# how to use html5 pushstate to make ajax page crawlable by search engines?

Tags: ajax, html, web-crawler, search-engine, pushstate

How to use HTML5 pushstate function to make ajax page crawlable by search engines? Search engines need to make an ajax request to retrieve the indexable content right? How is this related to changing the url in browser history?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications/13521668#13521668