# Is AngularJS safe for SEO now?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, google-search, googlebot

This question is not a duplicate of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications), which gives great information of the topic.

I'm specifically wondering, now, in **2014**, if I have to worry about Angular not rendering for GoogleBot, or GoogleBot penalizing load time.

Google says **[I don't have to worry](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html)** (sort of) but I *really* don't like to assume.

Specifically, I have a site which loads relatively immediately and then fetches AJAX content (like facebook's news feed does), and fills in the gaps with the content.

I know about `prerender.io` and I understand completely the concept of caching the page and delivering it to a search bot.  What I'm wondering is - is that necessary - and to take it a step further, what kind of leverage does that caching make for SEO.

---

## Scenario 1

PHP driven page which takes 1500ms to load all the content and display it.

## Scenario 2

Angular driven Single-Page-Application which loads in 500ms and then takes 1000ms to display AJAX data (1500ms total)

## Scenario 3

Use prerender (or similar) caching middleware, and render the same page in XXXms.

---

Is option 2 "safe"? for SEO, will Google rank this style harsher than the other two?

I'm actually quite impressed if Googlebot is going to sit around and wait 1000ms for that content to render, and index that result.  I think, in practice, this technique of rendering pages is much more user friendly ONLY if done correctly (and it's very easy to mess this up).

How confident can developers be who are cranking out SPAs that their content will be rendered correctly either for themselves or an end user client?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @AugieGardner What I mean is there's no real cost for a bot related to a server taking 1000ms to build its answer, which seems to be something you didn't take into account.

Comment: @dystroy I think it's impressive because, how does GoogleBot determine ultimate render scheme.  When *all* initial ajax requests are fulfilled?  In an Angular app, these requests may fire at slightly different times.  In a page where there is a main pane and a sidebar, One route (or state) may anychronously resolve before another state.  What's the discretion there?  It's really going to "wait" for that?  That is what interests me.

Comment: About a month ago I was getting {{var}} in search results for my site, and after a little while it went away. Not sure if it has anything to do with enabling webmaster tools on my page and telling google specific pages to index.