# AngularJs (ui.router) & Crawlers - Does the `!#` improve SEO?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, seo, google-search

**Routing:**
I use ui.router but my content is pretty static.

**Google:**
According to this thread ([How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)) there is no need to adjust something, because google seems to render javascript pages since May.I also looked to my webmaster tools and there is a correct Snapshot of my front-page.

But I'm still no quite sure, because I stumbled on these articles:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Question I:
They are old, but does the !# improve anything if I add it into my routing? The ajax calls are in my Routers/ I use resolve in the routes.

**Facebook**
If I share my page via facebook it gets nothing from the page but I added meta tags for facebook:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Rauchen aufhören" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Wir machen das Rauchen aufhören zu einem Game. Easy, effektiv und es fühlt sich gut an!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://quoking.com/modules/Home/images/fuck-the-cigarette-industry.jpg" />
```

In the service I use:
https://github.com/djds4rce/angular-socialshare
Is something mentioned about a HTML5 mode but that seems very complicated.

Question II:
Is there an easy fix if just want people to share my front-page & sub sites, with the initial view, without any DOM manipulations.? Or do I need a service like this:
https://prerender.io/ I anyways have less than 250 pages.

I mainly care about these two crawlers (maybe + Twitter if it is easy).

Comment: I am t he creator of the angular-socialshare plugin Using HTML5 model will help social networks count your url shares better, it wont help in any for Facebook crawling your site. Its a hard problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

> Question I: They are old, but does the !# improve anything if I add it
>   into my routing? The ajax calls are in my Routers/ I use resolve in
>   the routes.

Nope. As long as Google knows about your URLs (like in a `sitemap.xml`), it does not matter if they have `!#` or not.

For question II, see djd's comment.