# Google Fetch and Render only returns (what looks like) my index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, google-crawlers

Working with SEO and I'm trying to see how Google-bot is rendering my pages (Angular application). When I check the 'Fetch and Render' on various urls the images (the, "this is how a user sees your site/this is how google-bot sees your site") are never returned and the status says 'Partial'. Further, when I check the "Downloaded HTTP Response" every url has the same `index.html`-looking format to it, i.e. the pages aren't being rendered.

I've been reading a lot on SO as well as other sites about Google bots being able to render JS, as well as the old-school

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

technique ([discussed in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814524/angularjs-content-and-google)).

I'm definitely willing to try the 'older technique' even if [Google advises against it](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html), but I'd like to know why my site isn't being crawled correctly in the first place. Is it potentially a timing issue? Should I be using `prerender.io`?

Or, have I been overlooking something simpler? (fingers crossed)