# angular.js seo - google indexing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

my current html looks like this:

```
<title ng-bind="title">Loading</title>
<meta name="description" content="[[description]]">
<base href="/">
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

angular.js config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

I thought it's enough to let the googlebot index site correctly. But nope, it's not taking correct title or description. If I run "fetch as googlebot" site renders correctly..What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a prerendering engine to render the HTML for the bot. Read something here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io

And here about the `escaped_fragment` the bot uses to crawl your site: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification?hl=en

Comment: There is only this option "prerender" the site in HTML, you can use online services (without the need to install your prerender one) like this: https://prerender.io/

Comment: yeah, but I don't feel like paying for such service.

Comment: prerender is opensource, you can run in your own server - https://github.com/prerender/prerender

Comment: this is wrong. google does index plan JavaScript SPA sites.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you need to prerender your pages for the Google crawler anymore. A while back it started taking note of the javascript changes.

I've actually answered a question about [AngularJS seo that will help you here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005844/how-to-achieve-seo-in-angularjs-spa/32238360#32238360)

Look for my answer on the above link. I've also provided a directive that might be useful to you.

By the way, are you sure you are using the angularjs expression properly? You have decription using [[]] normally it is {{}}

Comment: I will take a look at link, thanks. And yeah, I'm sure I set custom syntax.

Comment: Vote the answer up if you think it'll help others. I think the current accepted answer is a whole lot more work than what i've mentioned, esp since it is no longer necessary I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Google will ignore the information provided in title or meta tags. But it looks more like a technically problem.

I would at least use ng-content-attr instead of writing it directly into the meta content attribute.

```
ng-attr-content="{{description}}"
```

Maybe Google extract your title information before anuglar has replaced it with the right string!

---

Another way is to use a directive that takes care of this for you. luckily i just wrote one.. just go ahead and try, you'll see with this setup google **will** recognize your title!
https://github.com/w11k/w11k-angular-seo-header/blob/master/angular-seo-header.js