# Should sites like ebay and amazon use frontend frameworks like angular js or vue js?

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel, frameworks, frontend

I'm thinking about upgrading my site. It's a trade place a lot like ebay.com.
My site is build in Laravel 5.1, but without any front-end framework. Because of that, I was wondering if it made any sense to use a front-end framework like angular js?

Pros and cons please.
I don't know that much about angular js, but if I convert my laravel application to fully obey the REST principles, i'm also well suited for building an iOS-app when that time comes???

http://tilsalg.dk - Link to my site

Answer (score -2):

I don't know whether it is suitable to use angularjs for this purpose. The problem is as far as I am concerned, that website which are written in javascript (so angular) can not be indexed well by SEO's. I'm hearing a lot that Google can index it but I'm a little sceptical about this. For a trading website like ebay it's very important that the site is SEO optimized. Of course if you use REST principles you can always change the frontend and that is also the way to do it.

Comment: you should do some research before making such statements. There are numerous approaches to setting SEO up on single page apps and guidelines are well established and documented by search engines

Comment: I think you're right. SEO is the foundation in these sites. I don't know why I haven't thought about that before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChristianGerdes there is no reason site can't properly be indexed

Comment: @charlietfl I found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications - And since you can't serve a pre-rendered version to the web-crawlers, it's kind of a mess perhaps??

Comment: @ChristianGerdes *"kind of a mess"* ... no not at all if you follow proper documented guidelines. I have numerous sites that run spa's and are well indexed

Comment: @charlietfl Like I said, I don't know that much about it. What would you suggest? Is it worth it? Use AngularJS or not?

Comment: @ChristianGerdes question itself is off-topic here as it is opinion based. You need to do your own research to make that determination. From a user perspective spa's are much faster which is why they are popular