# Angular.js Google Crawling

Tags: angularjs, ajax, seo, googlebot, google-crawlers

I used angular in my website. in specific part not whole website. google has a problem with indexing angular. So I used non angular part for google. but if ordinary user go to my website go to angular part. (I mean that I checked if (google or user) after that I go to non angular or angular). this is right? or google may add my site to black list?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://prerender.io/, as you can define some rules for any crawler in your server for that part of your website which uses Angular, So you don't need to customize views for user type.