# SEO in angular js without using third party integration

Tags: angularjs, node.js, seo

Is there a way to accomplish SEO in angular js without using third party integration like prerender,seo4ajax etc ??

Let me make it clear. Cant we do SEO by using angular js itself ??

I have gone through forums, stackoverflow. Found third party tools prerender and seo4ajax as first option for SEO in angular js. These third party tools provide SEO for limited pages only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, there a way to accomplish SEO in angular js without using third party integration(rendering from the server).

Search Engine Optimization (SEO) is making sure your site is structured in a way that search engines understand. 
Angular actually injects HTML into an already loaded page. This means that an Angular page is dynamic and does not require page reloading for an application to run. This is a problem to SEOs since that URL cannot be accurately indexed in this way.

Making your AngularJS applications more SEO-friendly is definitely worth doing. It is able to greatly improve the results showing up in Google search using some steps(without rendering from the server) which are given in the following link.
Please go through the below link. It will give you a good understand and best solution for your question.
https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/how-to-improve-seo-in-angularjs-applications