# angularjs rendering on server side asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, seo, isomorphic-javascript, rendr

I have used angularjs framework for front-end and asp net mvc for back-end to develop my web app.

As you know angularjs has a major flaw when it comes to SEO. There are some solutions like using phantomjs to create snapshots of website and serve it to search bot instead of original website. But I don't like it that way. I've recently introduced to the concept of isomorphic web apps and if I'm not mistaken it is possible to pre-render angularjs apps on server and then serve the rendered html to client.

All solutions I've found was for other frameworks. Like Rendr (https://github.com/rendrjs/rendr) or angularjs-server (https://github.com/saymedia/angularjs-server). Also there is a library called NodeServices (https://github.com/aspnet/NodeServices) that do the trick but it's written in Asp.net core and angular 2 universal that I use neither of them. Is there any library doing the same work for asp.net and angular?

Comment: For what its worth, [Google now executes JavaScript when crawling pages](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html), so the SEO impact of having a single-page app is pretty negligible these days.

Comment: @JoeClay As I checked in google search console, my webpage rendered correctly, but html content is not present. That is because of a known issue when using html 5 mode routing in angular . So I abandoned all partial solutions exists to make angular SEO friendly and I'm willing to fix the problem from root.

Comment: Good question, no answer. Have you had any success here?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to use phantom js.

Answer (score -1):

As stated here [How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)

Google now execute javascript when crawling the web. The problem is that a there's no standard, ,you can't assume that **any** search engine will correctly crawl your web application when is client-side rendered.

Comment: As you said "there is no standard" when search engines crawl client side rendered web apps so I want server side rendering. This is not an answer to my question.