# Can we use angularjs for job portals?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

For job portals, do we make SEO? If we use angularjs for jobportal site, will it make any issues on SEO?

Kindly help me to get an idea on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use angular for sure where ever you like its a JavaScript framework for applications. Now about SEO, earlier when angular came out there was not much stuff on SEO but If you do proper research (Google it) you will find tons of good articles about how to make your APP SEO friendly.

Since **May 2014** Google crawlers now executes JavaScript - you can use the Google Webmaster Tools to better understand how your sites are rendered by Google.

you could use PushState which changes the URL in the top browser bar without reloading the page. Say you have a page containing tabs. The tabs hide and show content, and the content is inserted dynamically, either using AJAX or by simply setting display:none and display:block to hide and show the correct tab content.

When the tabs are clicked, use pushState to update the url in the address bar. When the page is rendered, use the value in the address bar to determine which tab to show. Angular routing will do this for you automatically.

**Don't use HashBangs #!**
Hashbang urls were an ugly stopgap requiring the developer to provide a pre-rendered version of the site at a special location. They still work, but you don't need to use them.

Hashbang URLs look like this:

```
domain.com/#!path/to/resource
```

This would be paired with a metatag like this:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Google will not index them in this form, but will instead pull a static version of the site from the _escaped_fragments_ URL and index that.

Pushstate URLs look like any ordinary URL:

```
domain.com/path/to/resource
```

This question is already answered in detail by @superluminary If you click the following link you will find the original post and more useful stuff.

[How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23245379/4578345)

Comment: It really helps. Thank You @Waqas Khan!

Comment: @MuthuR I'm glad I was able to help, You are welcome :)