# How to make Google crawl an AngularJS application fine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, google-crawlers

Same websites after using html5mode and remove hashtags from url ["you do not need to serve different or pre-rendered content to Google"](https://allotment.digital/learn/technical-seo/advanced-concepts/angularjs-seo/) says.

In Google write ajax crawling documents deprecated. Other website write [Google can crawl an AngularJS fine](http://ng-learn.org/2014/05/SEO-Google-crawl-JavaScript/). In old stackoverflow question(s) the solution offers a different way.

If you dont use hashtags  you can put _escaped_fragment_ requests end of url to try how to see Google your website.

My AngularJS application uses html5mode and no needs hashtags(ex:www.domain.com/app/page-1). What should I do to be sure Google can crawl my AngularJS application fine ? Could you tell me more detail about crawling(I am not a senior).

Some informations without link because I could not post more than 2 links.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to see your question that you have already done quite a good research on AngularJs and Google Crawler, as you already know about most of the stuff there is very little to make sure if the bot is working as expected or not.

**Hashbang urls** are an ugly stopgap requiring the developer to provide a pre-rendered version of the site at a special location. They still work, but you don't need to use them.

Hashbang URLs look like this:

```
domain.com/#!path/to/resource
```

This would be paired with a metatag like this:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Google will not index them in this form, but will instead pull a static version of the site from the _escaped_fragments_ URL and index that.

Pushstate URLs look like any ordinary URL:

```
domain.com/path/to/resource
```

**Making Sure it Works:**
Google Webmaster tools now contains a tool which will allow you to fetch a URL as google, and render JavaScript as Google renders it. [Link to Googlebot-fetch](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch)

**AngularJs and Google Crawler Stuff:**

1: This is a wonderful article explaining everything in detail about [AngularJS SEO](https://prerender.io/js-seo/angularjs-seo-get-your-site-indexed-and-to-the-top-of-the-search-results/)
2: Also this question is already been answered by @superluminary in detail, please take a look Use [PushState and Precomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)
3: Some Answers more answers from a post I earlier wrote "[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37236969/4578345)"

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Google webmaster [today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) says. In same article **websites shouldn't pre-render pages only for Google** written. In other website [Prerender could cause cloaking](https://www.grobmeier.de/seo-and-angular-20012016.html) written and says it makes a risk. Really I need to use prerender.io or something like that. Thanks.

Comment: this may not longer be true, as Google has dropped support for prerendering and escaped fragments