# How to let robots parse our custom html elements?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, robots.txt

I have a website containing custom elements (i use angular 2), and google fails to parse them correctly :

It only sees

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

It seems that the value of this component is not retrieved at all by google robots.

Is there a best practice / workaround ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a million times. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13521668/2652883) question and [this](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) specific page by google.

> Times have changed. Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers. To reflect this improvement, we recently updated our technical Webmaster Guidelines to recommend against disallowing Googlebot from crawling your site's CSS or JS files.

Comment: If the question has been asked "a million times", why not flag as a duplicate as opposed to posting yet another answer?

Comment: Good question. I've never flagged a question before so this will be the first.

Comment: Don't downvote without any reasoning though.

Comment: I don't know where you're getting this from but it wasn't me. http://imgur.com/x6KRa2S

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is getting the HTML of your rendered page and inserting it into the `<my-app></my-app>` tags without user information or the like.

This will get replaced anyway after Angular has booted up, this means you can even put something completely different in there.

Comment: Why the downvote if I may ask? Exactly this has been promoted in many Angular 2 talks.