# Should I dynamically change title/alt tag of image for SEO?

Tags: html, angularjs, seo

I user angular in my application, where I have `ng-repeat` directive on images (which means, that in my HTML I have only one img tag for all image objects that I receive from server). Should I also include different titles and alt tags for these pictures? Does this matter from point of view of SEO?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming but SEO.

Comment: @Kyll kind of disagree here, as it's about the advisability of a programming practice rather than the typical "how to do X best for SEO" question (which I agree don't belong here). It's an issue in all these front-end libraries that generate stuff dynamically.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm not entirely sure. It still seems POB and/or too broad. In the light of [this meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281367/4174897), should this be flagged for migration to Webmasters?

Comment: Not sure, either. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications

Comment: @Pekka웃 — It's specifically about the effect it has on SEO, which is going to be speculative because hard data on how search engines treat such things is rather thin on the ground.

Comment: @Quentin I guess it's in the eye of the beholder... I read this to mean "if I change the title in Angular, will it be caught by search engine bots *at all*?" which seems relevant. But admittedly it's not exactly what OP is asking

Comment: This question on [webmasters.se]: [Should I dynamically change title/alt of image for SEO?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/98314/17633)

Answer (score -1):

Google search engine **consider** alt tags in their site ratings, so yeah it does matter if you have your alternative values, and moreover the content is also significant. Try using phrases, short and precise to describe your picture. In my opinion you can try extracting for example image name for alt without its extension. Like `<img src="images/bridge.jpg" alt="bridge">`. Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question, though - Angular is a front-end library and the question is whether values it sets dynamically will be seen by the Google crawler at all. Not whether alt tags are a good thing or not.

Answer (score -2):

Search engine spiders can only read initial requests without running JS code.

Site 1 uses javascript

```
<html>
<title></title>
<script>
document.title = 'Hello World!'
</script>
</html>
```

Site 2 uses html

```
<title>Hello World!</title>
```

The program will get the code but not be able to account for the javascript.  It will most likely use a regex to determine certain elements and the data in those elements.

Comment: "Search engine spiders can only read initial requests without running JS code" — That is not true of all search engine spiders.