# Google cannot index angular2 application

Tags: angular, seo, server-rendering

angular2 version: 2.0.0-beta.14

Hello, we built a web application with almost solely depending on client side angular2, however, since the release day - 3 days ago - google robots cannot index the pages properly.

When you hit the start page of the application from the google's webcache, it returns the following output:

[Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kubFT.png)

While these errors pop out, the network segment is works as expected. Also, the website can be normally reached without errors. If you need extra information, please just say.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've answered a post which its owner has some problems like yours. It might help you. Regards.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948082/6715875