# Replace variables in HTML source with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS recently but have some problems with that
I defined some scopes into like these

```
   app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
      $scope.siteURL = "my website url";
   });
```

and used this variable like {{siteURL}} in my html source code , But I see some errors in console because it does not change the source code and just compile it for browser . To avoid search engine errors Im looking for a way that can replace each scope with its value in **SOURCE code** before render in browser

I mean for some links and images like this I want Angular replace the value of scope in source not after compile HTML page :

```
<img src = '{{siteURL}}/img.jpg' />
```

to change

```
<img src = 'my website url/img.jpg' />
```

Answer (score 2):

> Im looking for a way that can replace each scope with its value in source code **before render** in browser

Angular can't help you here. It, being javascript, only works after page is loaded. What you need is some server-side language (PHP, node.js or whatever).

Comment: What I should to do to hide or ignore console errors about broken links on images ?

Comment: Don't emit broken img links. Or use `ng-src` instead of `src`

Comment: Thank you . Using ng-src or ng-href is so better but R U sure there is no error in seo report too ?!

Comment: @Mohamm6d: I have no idea about that. See your webmaster tools report as mastermind suggested.

Answer (score 1):

**Update May 2014**

Google crawlers now executes javascript - you can use the Google Webmaster Tools to better understand how your sites are rendered by Google.

DUPLICATE : [How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)

Else server-side is the only solution.

Comment: If I use ng-src so it should be okay for search engines ?!

Comment: no. Understand this thing that it will compile/render on client side(Browser).