# SEO contents are not read by Google in angularjs App

Tags: angularjs, seo, meta

I have developed an angularjs single page App. Meta tags and canonical link are dynamically set in each page. These contents are not shown in page source.It can be see while taking inspect element in browser.While we search our site in google,it doesn't show all pages and meta tags. We can see only index page in google search and the meta contents are not correct.

I have added these code in index.html page

```
 <title>Processuae</title><meta name="title" content="Processuae"><meta name="keyword" content="Management Consulting,Business Setup,Call Center Outsourcing,PRO & Document Clearing,Event & Exhibition Organization,Technology Support Services"><meta name="description" content="Process UAE is a company focused on providing a multitude of outsourcing services."><link rel="canonical" href="{{canonical_link}}">
```

In each page, i have added

```
<update-title title="{{page_title}}"></update-title><update-meta name="title" content="{{meta_title}}"></update-meta><update-meta name="keyword" content="{{meta_keyword}}"></update-meta><update-meta name="description" content="{{meta_description}}"></update-meta>
```

I have attached screenshots below
[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: [How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am refering this link "https://allotment.digital/learn/technical-seo/advanced-concepts/angularjs-seo/   ".But it is not working for me.