# Viewing page source. Cant see links or other page info

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I bought a template for a radio portal and the index page code is.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="80957862538-juiu2cgia32rn3lik36fv9a1ihc6fqof.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/player.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Listen Radio </title>
<base href="/">
 </head>
  <body ng-app="musiclistener">
<span ng-cloak>
    <span ng-view ></span>
</span>


<div id='player-container'>
    <audio controls id='music-player' src="#"></audio>

    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='col-sm-1 col-xs-3 text-center' id='play-icon-container'>
            <i class='fa fa-play' id='play-btn'  ng-click="playtoogle()"></i>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-1 center-block hidden-xs' id='podcast-icon-container'>
            <img src="{{ playerthumb }}"  id='play-img' class='img-responsive center-block'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-6' id='podcast-bar-container'>
            <span style='color:#fff;position:relative;top:3px;text-transform:capitalize' ng-if="musicplayingentity">{{ musicplayingentity}}</span>
            <div id='podcast-progress'>
                <div id='podcast-id-value'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-2 text-center hidden-xs' id='addons-icon-container'>

            <span ng-hide="userLoggedIn">
                <a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><i class='fa fa-plus pull-left'></i></a>          
                <a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><i class='fa fa-comment '></i></a>
            </span>

            <span ng-show ="userLoggedIn">
                <i ng-click="makeFavoritePlayer()" ng-hide="playingfav" class='fa fa-plus extrafun'></i>
                <i ng-click="removeFavoritePlayer()" ng-show="playingfav" class='fa fa-check extrafun'></i>
                <i ng-click="showCommentBoxPlayer()" class='fa fa-comment '></i>
            </span>

            <i class='fa fa-share pull-right' ng-click="shareboxPlayer()"></i>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-center' id='volume-container'>
                <div class='col-xs-2'>
                    <i class='fa fa-volume-up'></i>                     
                </div>
                <div class='col-xs-1 col-md-9'>
                    <div id='volume-progress'>
                        <div id='volume-id-value'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>  
<script src="ang/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="ang/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="ang/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="ang/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="ang/angular-facebook-sdk.js"></script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
  {
        FB.init({ appId      : '195962897544265',  xfbml : true,  version : 'v2.8'  });
  };
</script>
<script src="ang/app.js"></script>
<script src="ang/controllers.js"></script>
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='js/bootstrap.js'></script>
<script src='js/typed.js'></script>
<script src='js/wow.js'></script>
<script src='js/player.js'></script>
<script>
  new WOW().init();
</script>
<script>
  $(function(){
      $(".typing-text").typed({
        strings: ["MUSIC", "SPORTS", "BOOKS", "NEWS", "TALK"],
        typeSpeed: 200,
        backSpeed: 150,
        loop: true
      });
  });
</script>
```

If i visit the home page via my browser all the info is visable. But when i right click and view page source all I can see is the index page as layed out in the code above. I cant see any of the menu links, images, or any other info. Can someone please tell me why when I view page source I casnt see all info. The reason I ask it when google spiders my site it cant see my menus or images and so on, which is really bad for seo.

Any Ideas why.

Also if I right click on the home page and click inspect on chrome I can see all info.

Thanks

Comment: This is because you're using Angular, which populates the index page with all those elements dynamically. They don't 'belong' to the index, they are DOM insertions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications

Comment: This is not related at all to Google Analytics, is it?